# Uniqueness of the pushout complement in the category of sets

Tags: category-theory

In the category SETS (with sets as objects and total functions as morphisms), the pushout complement $C$ is unique up to isomorphism if the morphism $b$ is injective.

[image]

Rosen [2](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00289616) provides a proof in the category of graphs (Lemma 4.2) which feels very constructive and difficult. I would prefer a more “categorical proof”, but was not able to find one in the literature.

Can someone point me to literature or help outline the proof?

Comment: It seems that this property holds in [adhesive categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adhesive+category).

Comment: In the category of sets, if you want the pushout complement to exist, you need to have some conditions on the morphism $f$ (e.g. injectivity). For example, if some elements of $B \setminus A$ are identified with some elements of $A$ under $f$, you won't be able to make $D$ into a pushout.

Comment: @HuguesBellemare, the pushout exists and $b$ is injective. To my knowledge, this is enough for $C$ to be unique.

Comment: It seems like a simple proof would be to take the proof in SETS and carry it out in the internal logic (stack semantics) of the category of graphs, which is a topos.